# Functional data structure with backing store

Tags: java, functional-programming, architecture, monads, trie

As I'm working on my Functional Programming skills I'm trying to think about how I would approach a lazy trie we wrote in Java from a functional perspective.

The code is here but I'll highlight the details below: https://github.com/rsksmart/rskj/blob/master/rskj-core/src/main/java/co/rsk/trie/Trie.java

I'm only going to focus on the getter:
1. To get a value we might need to retrieve other nodes from disk
2. A "long value" might not be readily available, we need to retrieve it from disk too
3. The current code is not asynchronous, but I want that on the functional version

Regardless of the language, I want to understand the types involved in implementing this getter in a functional way.

I imagine having the following parameters:
1. The trie
2. The retrieve node function
3. The retrieve value function

If I define the type of any of the retrieve functions as some kind of Future/Promise/Task-returning type, then I assume my getter function will also have to return one of those.

If I squint hard enough, I can see that my getter does not depend on the actual async type. It just needs to work with the unwrapped values and return new wrapped ones, but how does it know what type to wrap them with? If I decided I want to do everything in memory and use unwrapped values, how could I use the same getter?

My main question is if this knowledge of the wrapping type is necessary, or if my poor knowledge of FP is my real problem. In that case, could you point me to any practical example of this?

Thank you!